# Check a date string (dd/mm/yyyy) is present in a sentence?

Tags: javascript, regex

How to check if a date string (dd/mm/yyyy) is present in a sentence using regex ??

Regex i used is below . It is not finding any matches .

```
var text = "...event held on 21/05/2018 at ...."
var match = text.match(/(\d{2})\/(\d{2})\/(\d{4})$/);
```

What is the efficient way to solve this?

Thanks advance!

Comment: The `$` means only match at the end of the string.

Comment: this ^ https://regexr.com/4686o. Unless you specifically want to group the seperate elements then the `()` are also unnecessary, `\d{2}\/\d{2}\/\d{4}` does the same thing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$` is an [anchor point in a regex](https://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html):

> They do not match any character at all. Instead, they match a position
>   before, after, or between characters.  ...
>   `$` matches right after the last character in the string.
>   `c$` matches c in `abc`, while `a$` does not match at all.

So your regex will only match if string **ends with** `21/05/2018`. You can simplify your regex to:

```
/\d{2}\/\d{2}\/\d{4}/
```

I've removed the matching groups (the braces `()`) because you don't implicitly need them. https://regexr.com/4686u

Answer (score 1):

`\d{2}\/(\d{2})\/\d{4}` is fine. The $ is unnecessary :)